# Problema despues de generar el apk para lanzamiento a google play store

Tags: android, flutter

tengo un problema que no se como resolverlo y que me tiene toda la tarde bregando. 
Bueno resulta que despues de hacer mis pruebas tanto en android como en ios que por cierto funcionaba todo bien perfectamente.
llego la hora de generar mi firma para luego mi apk para ya subirla a google play store , ahora procedo a decirle como lo hice que practicamente es lo q dice en la documentacion de flutter pero igual les dire por ahi me comi algo.

1) Cambie mi nombre de paquete en el archivo build.gradle que esta en el android/app/build.gradle (osea el principal gradle porque se que hay varios) como tambien cambie el numero de version y el nombre de version quedando asi:

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.loyaltyclubs.flutter"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
```

2) Tambien modifique el AndroidManifest.xml el que esta en el: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml 
Lo que cambie aqui solo fue el nombre del paquete al mismo que puse en el gradle en el paso uno quedando asi:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.loyaltyclubs.flutter">
```

Por si acaso solo modifique este archivo porque he visto que hay otros androidmanifest que estan en la carpeta profile/AndroidManifest.xml y otro en la carpeta debug/AndroidManifest.xml estas dos ultimas manifest no los he tocado solo el que esta en la carpeta main como dije anteriormente.

3) Ejecute en el terminal de vscode estando en mi carpeta de proyecto (la raiz) :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

bueno y como ustedes saben ahi piden algunos datos como contrasena , pais etc. yo los puse todo ok al final con un yes.

4) Cree un archivo en la carpeta principal de android  android/key.properties (el archivo key.properties)  y adentro he agregado el siguiente codigo:

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/admin/key.jks
```

bueno y ahi tienen los valores que le di al ejecutar el paso dos

5) he agregado , bueno he reemplazado parte del archivo principal build.gradle (el principal el que esta dentro de la carpeta app) quedando asi: bueno le dejare todo lo que tengo en el gradle  completo:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the 
local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
 flutterVersionCode = '1'
 }

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
 }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
 def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
 if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
 }

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

 defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.loyaltyclubs.flutter"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

  signingConfigs {
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : 
        null
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
 }
 buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
 }
```

bueno por si acaso todo esto que he hecho arriba en el gradle me guie de este enlace oficial de flutter:

[Enlace de donde me guie para modificar el gradle](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle)

que tambien me guie de esa pagina para hacer algunos pasos anteriores

6) bueno puej final mente termine guardando todo y al final hice el comando en la terminal de vscode

```
 flutter clean
 flutter build apk --release
```

ejecute el comando uno tras otro osea termina el primero y lo ejecuto el otro.
y bueno felizmente me genera mi apk para lanzarlo a google play store,  q se guarda en

```
build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

osea lo puedo ver dentro del vscode.

ahora yo probe ese .apk generado se lo mande a mi hermana por whatsapp web para hacerlo mas facil luego en mi celular entre al chat de mi hermana y descargue el apk a mi celular para instalarlo y lo instala todo perfectamente, PEROOOO al abrir la aplicacion se abre un tiempito el splashscreen la pantalla de splash y luego se cierra la aplicacion (cosa que no me sucedia ni con android e ios cuando estava haciendo pruebas osea presionando f5) y me sorprendio me fue rarisimo eso.

entonces lo que yo hice fue ejecutar desde vscode con f5 en un emulador android y en el debug console me muestra el sgt error:

se los dejo en una imagen.

[image: Este es el error que arroja en el debug console de vscode]

Bueno y lo extraño esque en ios si corre al presionar f5 desde vscode osea todo normal , por si acaso no he tocado nada para ios desde flutter.

bueno lo que mas yo he intentado a hacer es buscar:

```
   flavorName {
        applicationId = "com.example.loyal_flutter"
    }
```

y modificarle el paquete pero creo q no esta no lo he encontrado.

otra cosa que he hecho es cambiarle el paquete al AndroidManifest pero al AndroidManifest que esta en android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
quedando asi:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.loyaltyclubs.flutter">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

lo que hice aqui solo fue cambiar el paquete al que tiene el otro androidmanifest en el main principal, porque este androidmanifest que esta en la carpeta debug tenia otro paquete en el atributo package creo que era el por el default q flutter le pone era este :

```
com.example.loyal_flutter
```

el default que venia en ese manifest.

bueno entonces al cambiarle el maquete a ese archivo manifest y ejecutar nuevamente mi app desde vscode con f5  le cuento que no me tira error en android y esta todo ok pero , como antes solo muestra el splash de la app un ratito y luego se cierra la app.

bueno se que hay algo mal aqui porque yo uso git y al retroceder al ultimo commit que hice sin haber hecho nada de lo comentado arriba me funciona todo perfectamente en ios y android.

Agradeceria su ayuda que podria ser gracias de verdad. si hay algo mas que deba hacer o quieran ver de mi codigo se lo agradeceria muchas gracias.

aqui esta mi manifest de la carpeta main que me pidieron:

```
    <manifest 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.loyaltyclubs.flutter">
   <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an 
 android.app.Application 
     that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate 
     method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to 
      provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>     
   <application
    android:name= "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label= "Loyalty Flutter Base"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"

      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden 
     |keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale| 
     layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category 
    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate 
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
   </application>
   </manifest>
```

Por si acaso el paquete que se ve aqui `com.loyaltyclubs.flutter` tambien esta , es el mismo en el gradle principal

aqui esta mi main activity que me pidieron: esta en kotlin.
en este archivo no modifique nada yo.

```
  package com.example.loyal_flutter

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
 import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
 import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

 class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: 
 FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
   }
 }
```

bueno al parecer aqui estoy viendo que tiene otro nombre de paquete (al parecer el que me genero flutter por defecto) quizas este sea el error, pero igual lo publico como esta para ver que puedo hacer.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, borra todos los `AndroidManifest.xml` excepto el que está dentro de la carpeta `main`, quédate con ese.

Luego, agrégale el permiso de Internet :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Es en ese `AndroidManifest.xml` donde debes actualizar el paquete de tu app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_samples">
```

Usa el mismo package que tiene en tu `build.gradle`

en el MainActivity, cambia la primera linea del import por tu nuevo package.

Comment: holaa @diegoveloper te cuento que hice lo que me dijiste y no me funciono sigo con el mismo problema. borre los dos androidmanifest que en mi caso estavan en la carpeta debug y en la carpeta profile , que son las unicas que he visto que estan y me quede con el main , pero contarte que cuando genero mi apk con el paquete por default que me genera flutter y me funciona bien todo ok. muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Puedes agregar tu androidmanifest y tu mainactivity a la pregunta

Comment: ya lo agregue muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: Cambia la primera linea del MainActivity, está con el package viejo. Luego flutter clean, desinstala la app de tu celular e intenta de nuevo

Comment: Gracias amigo, ahora si me funciono :).

Comment: pero ahora quizas mi duda queda en porque flutter no lo modifico automaticamente o si siempre hay q hacer ese paso? me parecere raro, pero muchas gracias.

Comment: Depende del IDE que usas, creo que AndroidStudio te da la opción de elegir el paquete al inicio. Tambien puedes hacerlo por consola, creando el proyecto con: flutter create --org tupaquete

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias amigo me sirvio de mucho.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error indica:

> Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-40 value(com.example.loyal_flutter) has a
>   differente value (com.loyaltyclubs.flutter) declared in main manifest
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-39

**la sugerencia dice que remuevas la declaración del paquete dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` y se agregue dentro del `build.gradle` esto para evitar inconsistencias, como puedes ver en el mensaje se indica que tienes declarado diferente package name**.

Es correcto que dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` corrijas el nombre:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.loyaltyclubs.flutter">
```

Aunque la sugerencia indica modifiques el nombre de paquete dentro de un flavor,

```
   flavorName {
        applicationId = "com.loyaltyclubs.flutter"
    }
```

en realidad debes realizarlo en este punto, dentro del archivo `app/build.gradle` y los bloques `android` / `defaultConfig`:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.loyaltyclubs.flutter"
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    ...
    ...
 }
```

Por cierto, me parece que esto no es necesario probablemente fue copiado de un ejemplo, considera eliminar la definición de android:name y su valor :

```
  <application
    android:name= "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

Asegura que tu proyecto tiene la estructura que indica el paquete

```
com/
    ├── loyaltyclubs/
                    ├── flutter/
```

Limpia tu proyecto y vuelve a construirlo